# NetInfo has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed

Tags: react-native

salam
 after update react native appears this error

```
Warning: NetInfo has been extracted from react-native core
and will be removed in a future release.
It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/netinfo'
instead of 'react-native'. 
See https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
npm install --save @react-native-community/netinfo
react-native link @react-native-community/netinfo
```

and change this

```
import { NetInfo } from "react-native";
```

to:

```
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";
```